# shutil.make_archive throws UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I'm trying to zip some backups of a wordpress websites(a lot of files) via python's shutil.make_archive, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 432, in _encodeFilenameFlags
    return self.filename.encode('ascii'), self.flag_bits
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in position 61: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using python 3.6.1 and run it on heroku.

Here's the actual code that works in some cases and in some it doesn't:

```
zipped = shutil.make_archive( zip_file_name, 'zip', self.folder_path, self.time )
```

I hope someone can help me find a solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `zip_file_name` has non-English chars.

**Try:**

```
zipped = shutil.make_archive( zip_file_name.decode('utf8','surrogateescape'), 'zip', self.folder_path, self.time )
```

Comment: this gives me the following error: 

zipped = shutil.make_archive( zip_file_name.decode('utf8','surrogateescape'), 'zip', self.folder_path, self.time )
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'


i have the feeling that this might be a problem with the shutil.make_archive method